# Password-based chosen-basis computational Diffie-Hellman assumption

Tags: key-exchange, hardness-assumptions, pake

In [Simple Password-Based Encrypted Key Exchange Protocols](https://www.di.ens.fr/users/mabdalla/papers/AbPo05a-letter.pdf), the authors proposed a hard assumption as follows.

Experiment $Exp^{pccdh}_{\mathbb{G}, n}(\mathcal{A}, M, N, X^{'}, \mathcal{P})$

$(Y^{'}, st)\leftarrow \mathcal{A}(find, M, N, X^{'}, \mathcal{P})$

$k \stackrel{R}{\leftarrow} \{1, \cdot\cdot\cdot, n\}$; $r \leftarrow \mathcal{P}(k)$

$(K)\leftarrow \mathcal{A}(guess, st, k)$

$X \leftarrow X^{'}/M^{r}$; $Y \leftarrow Y^{'}/N^{r}$

if $K=CDH(X, Y)$ then $b\leftarrow 1$ else $b\leftarrow 0$

return $b$

Question：I do not know why this question is hard since the $Y^{'}$ is chosen by the adversary, the adversary can compute $K$ himself.

[image]

Comment: I just quickly read through but if I understand correctly the CDH inputs are actually $(X'/M^r, Y'/N^r)$ where $Y'$ is the only adversarially generated value. In which case I don't see how the adversary can easily compute the CDH unless they guess $r$ or solve the solving the previously defined CCDH.

Comment: Yes, your comment is useful. I forget that the adversary does not know the exponention of $M$ and $N$, so this is a hard assumption to the adversary.